# how to make this code more efficient with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, click, signals, psutil

hello i have written the below code to visit a website throw a proxy and click a button and then close the browser and repeat the about sets however with a different proxy. however the browser is not closing so there is a build up browsers.
here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os, re
import psutil
import signal

print("*" * 60)
print("LOL soul clicker")

print("*" * 60)


with open("working.txt", "r" ,encoding ="utf-8") as data:

    text=data.readlines()
data.close()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

def workclick(proxy, proxy_port):
    target_website = "https:www.website.com"

    proxy_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

    proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)

    proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", proxy )

    proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", proxy_port)

    proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", proxy )

    proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", proxy_port)

    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=proxy_profile)

    target_website = browser.get(target_website)
    time.sleep(6)
    target_website.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[2]   /div[1]').click()
target_website.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]').click()
target_website.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/article/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/i').click()


    browser.close()
def getpid():
    x = ""
    pn = "geckodriver.exe"
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == pn:
            x=int(str(proc).split(",")[0].split("=")[1])

    try:
        os.kill(x, signal.SIGTERM)
    except:
        os.kill(x, signal.SIGTERM)


k = len(text)
print(k)
for i in text:
    try:
        proxy, proxy_port = i.split(":")
        proxy = str(proxy)
        proxy_port = int(proxy_port)
        workclick(proxy, proxy_port)
        time.sleep(60)
        getpid()

        print(f"Success : {proxy}  {k}")

        k=k-1
    except:
        print(f"Failed : {proxy}    {k}")
        k=k-1
        getpid()
```

so i have trying simply debugging the code piece by piece in idle but i can not for the love of me seem to get the code to work correctly. basically i want to be able to click a button through a proxy several times

so i would greatly appreciate as much help as possible to get this script up and running to the best and most efficient way as possible thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first advices,

Firstly, Don't use sleep() , use wait until methods. It makes your tests more stable because sleep(6) is waiting 6 seconds every time and it can cause timing issues and also if elements does not appear on this time your code will fail. (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

After that you can use browser.quit() instead of browser.close().

Thirdly, If you will improve this code, try to work with your own libraries. You can write a custom methods which include what you wants, Then import them into your test files as a custom library.

For example: 
You can create SetProxy.py script and define proxies in this file as a custom function, then call them into test functions. It will be more maintainable when your code expands.